# running Wildfly-17 standalone failed to run due to unreasonable configuration exception

Tags: authentication, configuration, ldap, realm, wildfly

Configure Wildfly-17 for LDAP Authentication failed to run with exception telling that properties tag not allowed under authentication which is not reasonable As the exception says that the only allowed tags under authentication are:

```
|                 jaas        local       truststore  
|                 kerberos    plug-in     users       
|                 ldap        ***properties***
```

I tried to refresh the server then restart it, but still get the same exception
here is my standalone-full.xml configuration file:

```
<security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <ldap connection="EC2" base-dn="CN=Users,DC=mydc1,DC=mydc2,DC=org">
                        <username-filter attribute="sAMAccountName" />
                    </ldap>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
```

Here is the Exception message:

```
OPVDX001: Validation error in standalone-full.xml ------------------------------
|
|  50:         <username-filter attribute="sAMAccountName" />
|  51:     </ldap>
|  52:     <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
|          ^^^^ 'properties' isn't an allowed element here
|               
|               Elements allowed here are: 
|                 jaas        local       truststore  
|                 kerberos    plug-in     users       
|                 ldap        properties  
|
|  53: </authentication>
|  54: <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
|  55:     <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
|
| 'properties' is allowed in elements: 
| - server > management > security-realms > security-realm > authentication
| - server > management > security-realms > security-realm > authentication > plug-in
| - server > management > security-realms > security-realm > authorization
| - server > management > security-realms > security-realm > authorization > plug-in
| - server > management > outbound-connections > ldap
```

Comment: Just in case, did you try to edit the file ensuring there is no special character left except \n  and whitespaces between `</ldap>` and `<properties path=...`, same for the string 'prＯOoperties' ;)

Comment: yes I ensure there is no special character not even any of white spaces

Comment: @EricLavault I will update my question including the configuration code

Comment: Try adding the properties element as the first entry. Generally speaking too it's best to use the management console or CLI to make changes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting the properties element first solve the problem